# Checklist-model automatically checking all checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

When I click on one checkbox, I am expecting only that checkbox to be marked.  For some reason, however, when I click on one checkbox, they are all getting marked.

```
<label ng-repeat="group in groups" id="mast" class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedGroups.group" checklist-value="value" checklist-change="change()">
    Group {{$index + 1}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because of `checklist-value="value"`. The value property is the same for each instance of the ng-repeat.

Try to replace by `checklist-value="group.value"`.

Comment: Thanks mate.  That got me close.  I had to change it to `checklist-value="group"` and then it worked correctly.